# Check value from whole table that match where clause in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch data from table where there are multiple column, but i want to get only those rows which have both code represented with single name. Like

```
  customer_id     code   
  ct001           abc
  ct002           xyz
  ct001           xyz
  ct003           abc
```

here no value is unique or primary key, now query should return only **ct001** as it has both codes present i.e. **abc** & **xyz** .

how to achieve this right now i am trying using this query.

```
$sql = "SELECT *  FROM code_table WHERE code IN ('abc' ,'xyz') 
        AND customer_id= '" .$row['customer_id'] . "'";
```

i am getting customer id from another table and using this query in loop

Comment: Apart from the actual question, I'd consider **not** using concatenation to build the query string. Try prepared statements / parameterized queries. Otherwise you'll find yourself in the hell of SQL injection victims.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT code 
FROM code_table
WHERE code IN ('abc', 'xyz') 
GROUP BY code
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

You should not be doing loops in application code when you can let the database do the work for you.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks Gordon.